# spark Join performance on EMR cluster

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs

We have 3 Node spark EMR cluster(m3Xlarge). We are trying to Join some big tables have size 4GB (250+ columns) and several small referencetable (15) have 2-3 columns each. Since we are using spark dynamicallocation that is default enabled in EMR.

So while writing to HDFS it is taking 1+ hour to save results(This is because we are using coalesce(1) on final DataFrame).

Even we tried to use broadcast joins but no luck yet. how can we improve the Performance for the above?

What will be the optimize final execution time for the above Process?

What can be the Possible ways that can improve Performance?

Any help will be appreciated !

Here is My join function

```
def multiJoins(MasterTablesDF: DataFrame, tmpReferenceTablesDF_List: MutableList[DataFrame], tmpReferenceTableJoinDetailsList: MutableList[Array[String]], DrivingTable: String): DataFrame = {

// Define final output of Driving Table
var final_df: DataFrame = null

if (MasterTablesDF != null) {

  if (!MasterTablesDF.head(1).isEmpty && tmpReferenceTablesDF_List.length >= 1) {

    for (i <- 0 until tmpReferenceTablesDF_List.length) {

      val eachReferenceTableDF = tmpReferenceTablesDF_List(i)
      var eachJoinDetails = tmpReferenceTableJoinDetailsList(i)

      //for first ref table Join
      if (i == 0) {
        println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
        if (eachJoinDetails(0).equals(eachJoinDetails(1))) {
          println("############## Driving table and Ref table Joining columns are same joining first Drive table ==>" + DrivingTable + "With Ref table ==>" + eachJoinDetails(3))
          //if reftable and Driving table have same join columns using seq() to remove duplicate columns after Joins
          final_df = MasterTablesDF.join(broadcast(eachReferenceTableDF), Seq(eachJoinDetails(0)), eachJoinDetails(2)) //.select(ReqCols.head, ReqCols.tail: _*)
        } else {
          //if the joining column names of the driving and ref tables are not same then
          //using  driving table join col and reftable join cols
          println("############### Driving table and Ref table joining columns are not same joining first Drive table ==>" + DrivingTable + "With Ref table ==>" + eachJoinDetails(3) + "\n")
          final_df = MasterTablesDF.join(broadcast(eachReferenceTableDF), MasterTablesDF(eachJoinDetails(0)) === eachReferenceTableDF(eachJoinDetails(1)), eachJoinDetails(2))

        }

      } //Joining Next reference table dataframes with final DF
      else {
        if (eachJoinDetails(0).equals(eachJoinDetails(1))) {
          println("###### drive table and another ref table join cols are same joining driving table ==>" + DrivingTable + "With RefTable" + eachJoinDetails(3))
          final_df = final_df.join(broadcast(eachReferenceTableDF), Seq(eachJoinDetails(0)), eachJoinDetails(2)) //.select(ReqCols.head, ReqCols.tail: _*)
          // final_df.unpersist()
        } else {
          println("######  drive table and another ref table join cols are not same joining driving table ==>" + DrivingTable + "With RefTable" + eachJoinDetails(3) + "\n")
          final_df = final_df.join(broadcast(eachReferenceTableDF), MasterTablesDF(eachJoinDetails(0)) === eachReferenceTableDF(eachJoinDetails(1)), eachJoinDetails(2))

        }
      }
    }

  }
}

return final_df

//Writing is too slow
//final_df.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("delimiter", "|").option("header", "true")
      .csv(hdfsPath)

}
```

Is this fine ? is this due to looping ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably Spark can't optimize your very long execution plan as good as possible. I had same situation and we did a series of optimizations:
1) remove all unneccessary columns  and filter as soon as possible
2) "Materialize" some tables before joining, it will help Spark to break lineage and somehow optimize your flow(in our sample 2 sortJoins were replaced by broadcast joins, because Spark realized that dataframes is very small)
3) We partitioned all datasets by same key and number of partitions(right after read). 
and some other optimizations.. It reduced job time from 45 mins to 4. You need closely look at Spark UI, there we found a lot of helpful insights to optimize(one of our executor worled instead of 10 because of all data was partitioned in one part..) etc.. Good luck!

Comment: thanks @Andrei is it good to remove coalese(1) and let spark writes data to hdfs later call some hdfs command/shell script to merge all part files to single. Also i have added brodcast(small) table in joins.

Comment: I thought about that but quick experiments showed that it not gain much improvements, so I skipped tthis optimization, because we achieved it another way. Try it and share results - it can be interesting. However, it can't take so much time anyway, you need to find error before save. For comparison, writing with coalesce(1) and 3  GB of output to one csv file taking max 1 min on my EMR cluster and scales linearly

Comment: Hi Andrei , by removing coalese(1) and using some external script to merge partfile it reduced execution time from 1 hour to 18 min. Also i am reading Master i.e big table file from s3 using                s3LoadToDF = spark.read.
        option("header", "false").
        option("delimiter", "|").
        csv(s3ReadPath)

Comment: bellow spark submit i am using , you can suggest some edits.EMR cluster4node m3.xlarge instance type,                                                                           spark-submit --class sparkJoins.main --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --driver-memory 10g --num-executors 4 --executor-cores 3 --executor-memory 4g --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false --conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=1000 --files spark_join.conf,/home/hadoop/scripts/hdpScript.sh sparkJoins.jar 
what will be the sql.shuffle partion/parallelizm. can you suggest edits in spark-submit?